# Is there a more efficient way to select rows from a PyArrow table based on contents of a column?

Tags: python, pyarrow

I asked [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64578761) about a more idiomatic way to select rows from a PyArrow table based on contents of a column. The answer from @joris looks great. But it looks like selecting rows purely in PyArrow with a row mask has performance issues with sparse selections.

Is there a more efficient way to do this, but stay purely in PyArrow without going back and forth between PyArrow and numpy?

Test case:

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Example table for data schema:
# Alternating rows with index 0 and 1
irow = np.arange(2**20)
dt = 17
df0 = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': np.array((irow//2)*dt, dtype=np.int64),
                   'index':     np.array(irow%2, dtype=np.int16),
                   'value':     np.array(irow*0, dtype=np.int32)},
                   columns=['timestamp','index','value'])
ii = df0['index'] == 0
df0.loc[ii,'value'] = irow[ii]//2
ii = df0['index'] == 1
df0.loc[ii,'value'] = (np.sin(df0.loc[ii,'timestamp']*0.01)*10000).astype(np.int32)

# Insert rows with index 2 every 16 timestamps
irow = np.arange(10000)
subsample = 16
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': np.array(irow*dt*subsample, dtype=np.int64),
                    'index':     np.full_like(irow, 2, dtype=np.int16),
                    'value':     np.array(irow*irow, dtype=np.int32)},
                    columns=['timestamp','index','value'],
                    index=irow*subsample*2+1.5)
df2=pd.concat([df0,df1]).sort_index()
df2.index = pd.RangeIndex(len(df2))
print(df2)
table2 = pa.Table.from_pandas(df2)

# which prints:

         timestamp  index   value
0                0      0       0
1                0      1       0
2                0      2       0
3               17      0       1
4               17      1    1691
...            ...    ...     ...
1058571    8912845      1    9945
1058572    8912862      0  524286
1058573    8912862      1    9978
1058574    8912879      0  524287
1058575    8912879      1    9723

[1058576 rows x 3 columns]
```

to verify there is sparse content with index=2:

```
print(df2[df2['index']==2])

# which prints

        timestamp  index     value
2               0      2         0
35            272      2         1
68            544      2         4
101           816      2         9
134          1088      2        16
...           ...    ...       ...
329837    2718640      2  99900025
329870    2718912      2  99920016
329903    2719184      2  99940009
329936    2719456      2  99960004
329969    2719728      2  99980001

[10000 rows x 3 columns]
```

and benchmarking:

```
import time

# My method, which sloshes back and forth between PyArrow and numpy
def select_by_index_np(table, ival):
    value_index = table.column('index').to_numpy()
    row_indices = np.nonzero(value_index==ival)[0]
    return table.take(pa.array(row_indices))

# Stay in PyArrow: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64579502/44330
def select_by_index(table, ival):
    value_index = table.column('index')
    index_type = value_index.type.to_pandas_dtype()
    mask = pc.equal(value_index, index_type(ival))
    return table.filter(mask)

def run_timing_test(table, ival, select_algorithm, nrep=100):
    t1 = time.time_ns()
    for _ in range(nrep):
        tsel = select_algorithm(table, ival)
    t2 = time.time_ns()
    print('%.0fus %20s(%s) -> %s' % 
          ((t2-t1)/1000/nrep, 
           select_algorithm.__name__, 
           ival, 
           tsel.column('value').to_numpy()))

run_timing_test(table2, 0, select_by_index)
run_timing_test(table2, 0, select_by_index_np)
run_timing_test(table2, 1, select_by_index)
run_timing_test(table2, 1, select_by_index_np)
run_timing_test(table2, 2, select_by_index)
run_timing_test(table2, 2, select_by_index_np)

# which prints

7639us      select_by_index(0) -> [     0      1      2 ... 524285 524286 524287]
7780us   select_by_index_np(0) -> [     0      1      2 ... 524285 524286 524287]
7789us      select_by_index(1) -> [   0 1691 3334 ... 9945 9978 9723]
8204us   select_by_index_np(1) -> [   0 1691 3334 ... 9945 9978 9723]
3840us      select_by_index(2) -> [       0        1        4 ... 99940009 99960004 99980001]
1611us   select_by_index_np(2) -> [       0        1        4 ... 99940009 99960004 99980001]
```

The two methods are comparable when selected rows are a substantial portion of the table, but when they are very small, `select_by_index_np` which marshals to numpy, determines indices where the rows of the mask are True, and marshals back to PyArrow, is faster!

Is there an efficient way to do this but stay in PyArrow? (I don't see any pyarrow.compute equivalent to `numpy.nonzero`)

Comment: Indeed, for this specific case, the numpy version is faster. I did some similar timings on a simplified example, and there it was actually the case with selecting more rows which was faster in numpy. In any case an indication that there is room for improvement on the Arrow side, so I opened https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-10423 to track this